# How to colorize sqlite3 text in Virtual Studio Code

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am trying to make my sqlite code more readable but have failed miserably to find how to change the settings. When I type in something like this anything between the doc string quotes stays the same color as comments, whilst in sublime it gets colorized in a very convenient way.

```
def create_table():
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(
    parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, 
    parent TEXT, 
    comment TEXT,
    subreddit TEXT,
    unix INT, 
    score INT)""")
```

Python is installed through anaconda:

Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I am running the code through a virtual environment defined in the anaconda navigator